# excel 2007: error 5, invalid procedure call or argument when try to open foxit reader

Tags: pdf, excel, vba

I have an excel with two columns, one for the relative path of the pdf file and other column with the number page that I want to open.

In one computer, the excel works fine, when I double click in a row, excel calls to foxit reader and open the document.

However I have other computer in which this excel does not work. I get the error 5: invalid procedure call or argument.

How it works in one computer without problems, I think that the problem is in the other computer, not in the VBA code, but I don't know what it can be the problem.

Which can be the cause of this error?

In both computers I use excel 2007 and I enabled macros when it prompts. In the computer that it works fine, I use windows 7 x64 and in the other computer I have windows 7 x86.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you show the relevant code just in case?

Comment: My best guess in such a scenario would be to re-install foxit reader on the computer where it doesn't work and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem seem to be in the path of the files, in which I need to use double quiotes to solve the problem. In my case I have three string variables:

```
pathReader: the path to the foxit
pathDocument: the path to the pdf document
numberPage: has /A page=x where x is the number page that I have in the cell.
```

Then I create a commnad:

```
command = """" & pathReader & """" & " " & """" & pathDocument & """" & " " & numberPage
```

Finally I execute the command

```
Shell command, vbMaximizedFocus
```

With the number page is not needed to use the double quotes.

It's seems that in some computers it can be possible to have problems with the path of the files, perhaps with the blank spaces, so with the double quotes the problem is solved.

For my experience, this problem does not occur always, in all the computers, but is better to use this solution because is more generic.